# How can I host the folder's content for anyone to access and have my device act as a server while it's running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socketserver, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to share a folder for anyone to access while running the code by making my local machine act as a server

```
PORT = 8000
DIRECTORY = "/content/sample_data"
class Handler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=DIRECTORY, **kwargs)
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal, move to the directory that you want to give access to and run:

```bash
python -m http.server 8000
```

You will have a local server running on the port 8000.

If you don't have a public ip address you can use ngrok to get one:

Install ngrok, open another terminal and run

```bash
ngrok http 8000
```

Now anyone can access your folder by requesting the ngrok endpoint.

Comment: Thank You ! @Kkameleon but I need it as a python script with an input Directory path and output shareable URL (how can I get the  output URL ) and am not sure if this code (code in the question ) gives result cause I cannot test if the folder is shared or not because I cannot get the URL it just still running

Comment: The local url is http://localhost:8000 but it won't be accessible publicly. You need to use a service that will provide you a public ip address to do what you want, if you don't have one  already. The best solution for the problem you describe is what I wrote above in my answer. You can call the bash commands in a python script if you want.